# How do you get a Textbox to Read line by line by label.text

Tags: vb.net

Okay so I fell into a loop and got stumped. I have been trying many ways to try and get a VB.net (Label.text) to = each independent line entered. Is there an easier alternative that will not come up with warnings? Just Curious. I could use a Listbox to Manage the Items and use those lines instead of a Textbox in Multi-lined, Just wondering how to get multi line function that reads text from a textbox to a label.text if many lines are entered. 
For Example.

If ProgressBar1.Value = 0% Then Label10.Text = (TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine)
Problem with this is that it Addes it all into the Label. Id like a way to have line by line be shown by the Label.text. Sorry If this is coming off confusing to any of you haha.
Thanks
~Tom

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that your Label has property 'AutoSize', which must be set to 'False'

Answer (score 0):

Create a string array by spliting the `textbox.text` using `Environment.NewLine`.
Then you can select the proper line to display on the label from that array depending on your business logic.